# List down store names according to letter button selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to list down store names according to alphabetic button pressed.
For e.g If i press 'A' button it should list down store names starting from letter A. I know that i should use LIKE query for this. But is their anyway to make it simpler? or a single query that could process it easily with php.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-default">All stores</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">A</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">B</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">C</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">D</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would map the first letter of each store to a number and then store that number as the key of an array. Then you just need to present a subset of that array based on the user selection.

- A -> 1
- B -> 2
- C -> 3
- ...

Then if someone selects B, you would return your list from 2. So in Mysql it might look something like this

where MapStoreValue >= 2;

or If you load all the values in an array in php you could do for example do something like this:

```
// if your $stores array looks like this
$stores = array(
    1 => 'A',
    2 => 'B',
    3 => 'C',
    4 => 'D'
);
```

then you can simply return the desired subset of that array.

```
var_dump(array_slice($stores, 1));

// this returns: [2 => B, 3 => C, 4 => D]
```

Comment: And what if i use  IfElse  to do so? Will it be convenient?

Comment: I would not use if else, that would mean you need to have a if else block for each case. I will update my answer with some code you can use

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said you don't want to use MySQL, but here is a solution for others then (not tested):

```
<?php

/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

// Try to create a connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ';

// Get the letter selected
$letter = isset($_POST['letter']) ? $_POST['letter'] : '';

// If letter is not empty
if(!empty($letter)){
    // Query continued
    $sql .= 'WHERE store_name LIKE :letter';
}

// The prepared statement
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// Binding the value of the $letter to the query
if(!empty($letter)){
    $sth->bindValue('letter', "$leẗter%");
}

// Executing the query
$sth->execute();

// Fetching the results
$stores = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCT_OBJ);
```